# How to wrap simple classes into a Module in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an application that has many simple "Model" classes that are used in a lot of places. I have ended up with many imports, importing all of these from there individual files.

In a test app (It is Ionic4/Angular, but should be the same for any Angular app), I have attempted to wrap a couple of classes into a Module, so I could then consume via just one import statement.

[image]

Each Model class is just a plain class, eg

```
export class Model1 {
  public name:string;
}
```

And in `modules.module.ts`, I have the following...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Model1 } from './model1';
import { Model2 } from './model2';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],

  exports:[Model1, Model2]
})
export class ModelsModule { }
```

I now wish to consume this in the `HomeModule`

In `home.module.ts` I have the Models module imported..

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    ModelsModule,  <------ my import
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

All looked good so far.

Now I wanted to consume the Models in the `home.page.ts`..

I added the import..

`import { Model1, Model2 } from '../models/models/models.module';`

However the IDE (VSCode) now shows the the following error..

`Module '"../models/models/models.module"' has no exported member 'Model1'.ts(2305) import Model1`

I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Am I able (and is it recommended) to use `Modules` is such a way, or is there some better way of doing what I am after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are doing a mistake, You cannot export an interface/class. You can only export:

```
Other modules
Components
Directives
Pipes
```

You should have your models as a separate folder but not within a module. **`NgModule`** is an angular concept and should not be confused with a typescript module.

Comment: Oh ok. So is there any way to "bunch" a collection of classes as I have?

Comment: you could create a typescript module.d.ts as explained here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

Comment: did that help ?

Comment: Actually, a bit of experimenting, all I need to do is export all the classes from another single ts file.Eg have a models.ts with the following `export{ Model1} from './model1';
export { Model2} from './model2';`. And I can then just import from the one file.. `import { Model1, Model2 } from '@models/models';`

Comment: yeah thats what i have mentioned in the answer

Comment: actually what I did was the same as you suggested (except I didn't have the `.d`. OK thanks